# How to query another attribute from next level of XML hierarchy in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery

I'm quite new to xml and need some help for querying a xml column within SQL Server 2012.

So far I have the following statement:

```
SELECT sel.value('@name', 'varchar(max)')  AS SelectionParamterNames
FROM [schm].[sometable] T1
CROSS APPLY Selection.nodes('//syntax/selections/selection') R(sel)
```

So far so good since I get back the expected values from the third hierarchy:

SelectionParameterNames

1. SomeSelName_A
2. SomeSelName_B

But what I also need is the attribute `name` from `<actionobject>` (if existing, `SomeSelName_B` doesn't have it)

I thought this would do it:

```
    SELECT   sel.value('@name', 'varchar(max)')  AS SelectionParamterNames
           , sel.value('.//@name', 'varchar(max)')  AS SelectionProcedureNames
    FROM [schm].[sometable] T1
    CROSS APPLY Selection.nodes('//syntax/selections/selection') R(sel)
```

and I expected:

```
SelectionParameterNames | SelectionProcedureNames
--------------------------------------------------     
 1. SomeSelName_A       | sp_someprocedure_a 
 2. SomeSelName_B       | NULL
```

but what I get back is:

> XQuery [Structure.TM_TemplateVersion.Selection.value()]: 'value()'
>   requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type
>   'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

I spent quite some time coming this far and understanding the syntax but time is running and I need some help.

Much appreciated, Pete

XML Content:

```
<syntax type="Selection">
  <selections>
    <selection type="Selection" name="SomeSelName_A" caption="SomeSelCaption_A" control="List" multivalue="True" clonetemplate="False" description="">
      <actionobject type="DbObject" datasourcename="SomeSource" objecttype="StoredProcedure" schema="schm" initialsql="schm.sp_someprocedure_a 1" name="sp_someprocedure_a">
        <parameters>
          <parameter name="@p_parameter_a" type="Parameter" datatype="Int" inputtype="Constant" inputvalue="1" required="False" iskey="False" />
          <parameter name="@p_parameter_b" type="Parameter" datatype="Int" inputtype="Constant" inputvalue="1" required="False" iskey="False" />
        </parameters>
        <columns>
          <column name="SomeColID_A" type="Column" datatype="Int" iskey="False" useas="Value" />
          <column name="SomeColName_A" type="Column" datatype="VarChar" iskey="False" useas="Text" />
        </columns>
      </actionobject>
    </selection>
    <selection type="Selection" name="SomeSelName_B" caption="SomeSelCaption_B" control="Calender" multivalue="false" clonetemplate="False" description="" />
  </selections>
</syntax>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **tell** your XQuery that you want to access the `<actionobject>` subnode!

Use this statement:

```
SELECT   
    SelectionParamterNames = sel.value('@name', 'varchar(max)'),
    SelectionProcedureNames = sel.value('(actionobject/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    [schm].[sometable] T1
CROSS APPLY 
    Selection.nodes('/syntax/selections/selection') R(sel)
```

and you should get the output you're looking for.

This will work if your `<selection>` nodes always contain at most one element of type `<actionobject>` - and it will read the `name` attribute of that element - if present (otherwise you get back `NULL`)

**Update:** if you could have multiple `<actionobject>` nodes under `<selection>`, then you need to do a "nested" `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT   
    SelectionParamterNames = sel.value('@name', 'varchar(max)'),
    SelectionProcedureNames = ActObj.value('@name', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    [schm].[sometable] T1
CROSS APPLY 
    Selection.nodes('/syntax/selections/selection') R(sel)
CROSS APPLY
    sel.nodes('actionobject') AS XmlTbl(ActObj)
```

This way, you can handle multiple subnodes and extract their attributes as needed

Comment: Thank you so much! one more thing though. I now figure that I have to tell which subnode to go to and by using [1] I tell it to give back the specified value from the 'first' element. Now what if there are n elements how do I tell to give back every of those. In the provided xml sample I would want to get back "@p_parameter_a" and "@p_parameter_b"

Comment: @Pete: updated my response to show how to handle multiple subnodes - if those exist

Comment: This helps so much not only solving my problem but understanding! Many thanks!

Comment: @Pete: glad to share and help, if I can !