# SQL Server XML namespace colon

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have an XML I am trying to parse to table. I have managed this with similar but different XML.

It looks like this:

```
<del:DeliverMeterReading xmlns:del="http://schemas.fortum.com/amm/delivermeterreading">
  <del:Header>
    <del:MessageId>x</del:MessageId>
    <del:MessageType>y</del:MessageType>
    <del:MessageCreatedTimestamp>2021-10-27T22:10:25.362+00:00</del:MessageCreatedTimestamp>
    <del:MessageReceivedTimestamp>2021-10-27T22:10:31+00:00</del:MessageReceivedTimestamp>
    <del:DispatchId>z</del:DispatchId>
  </del:Header>
  <del:DataRows>
    <del:Data>
      <del:TaskTypeId>0</del:TaskTypeId>
      <del:TaskId>1</del:TaskId>
      <del:DeliverySiteEANCode>1</del:DeliverySiteEANCode>
      <del:SvkCode>901</del:SvkCode>
      <del:MeterId>-1</del:MeterId>
      <del:DeliveryFormat>E</del:DeliveryFormat>
      <del:ReadingStartDate>2021-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00</del:ReadingStartDate>
      <del:ReadingEndDate>2021-08-28T23:00:00.000+00:00</del:ReadingEndDate>
      <del:Resolution>PT1H</del:Resolution>
      <del:SpSla />
      <del:RecordPosition>1</del:RecordPosition>
      <del:Values>
        <del:Value position="1" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96542.26" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846141" />
        <del:Value position="2" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96542.54" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846142" />
        <del:Value position="3" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T02:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T02:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96542.79" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846143" />
        <del:Value position="4" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T03:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T03:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96543.06" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846144" />
        <del:Value position="5" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T04:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T04:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96543.31" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846145" />
        <del:Value position="6" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T05:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T05:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96543.58" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846146" />
        <del:Value position="7" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T06:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T06:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96543.99" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846147" />
        <del:Value position="8" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T07:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T07:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96544.43" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846148" />
        <del:Value position="9" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T08:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T08:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96544.89" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846149" />
        <del:Value position="10" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T09:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T09:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96545.29" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846150" />
        <del:Value position="11" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T10:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T10:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96546.02" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846151" />
        <del:Value position="12" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T11:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T11:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96547.37" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846152" />
        <del:Value position="13" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T12:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T12:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96548.04" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846153" />
        <del:Value position="14" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T13:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T13:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96549.92" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846154" />
        <del:Value position="15" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T14:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T14:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96550.69" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846155" />
        <del:Value position="16" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T15:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T15:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96551.69" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846156" />
        <del:Value position="17" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T16:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T16:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96553.68" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846157" />
        <del:Value position="18" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T17:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T17:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96555.07" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846158" />
        <del:Value position="19" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T18:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T18:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96557.56" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846159" />
        <del:Value position="20" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T19:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T19:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96558.36" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846160" />
        <del:Value position="21" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T20:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T20:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96559.01" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846161" />
        <del:Value position="22" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T21:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T21:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96559.82" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846162" />
        <del:Value position="23" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T22:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T22:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96560.44" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846163" />
        <del:Value position="24" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T23:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T23:00:00.000+00:00" reading="96560.83" status="51" meterReadingId="1459846164" />
      </del:Values>
    </del:Data>
    <del:Data>
      <del:TaskTypeId>0</del:TaskTypeId>
      <del:TaskId>2</del:TaskId>
      <del:DeliverySiteEANCode>2</del:DeliverySiteEANCode>
      <del:SvkCode>901</del:SvkCode>
      <del:MeterId>-1</del:MeterId>
      <del:DeliveryFormat>E</del:DeliveryFormat>
      <del:ReadingStartDate>2021-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00</del:ReadingStartDate>
      <del:ReadingEndDate>2021-08-28T23:00:00.000+00:00</del:ReadingEndDate>
      <del:Resolution>PT1H</del:Resolution>
      <del:SpSla />
      <del:RecordPosition>2</del:RecordPosition>
      <del:Values>
        <del:Value position="1" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T00:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126748.93" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846165" />
        <del:Value position="2" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T01:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126749.71" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846166" />
        <del:Value position="3" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T02:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T02:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126750.49" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846167" />
        <del:Value position="4" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T03:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T03:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126751.27" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846168" />
        <del:Value position="5" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T04:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T04:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126752.06" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846169" />
        <del:Value position="6" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T05:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T05:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126752.84" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846170" />
        <del:Value position="7" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T06:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T06:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126753.62" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846171" />
        <del:Value position="8" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T07:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T07:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126754.4" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846172" />
        <del:Value position="9" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T08:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T08:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126755.18" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846173" />
        <del:Value position="10" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T09:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T09:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126755.96" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846174" />
        <del:Value position="11" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T10:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T10:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126756.74" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846175" />
        <del:Value position="12" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T11:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T11:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126757.52" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846176" />
        <del:Value position="13" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T12:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T12:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126758.3" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846177" />
        <del:Value position="14" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T13:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T13:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126759.08" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846178" />
        <del:Value position="15" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T14:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T14:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126759.86" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846179" />
        <del:Value position="16" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T15:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T15:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126760.64" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846180" />
        <del:Value position="17" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T16:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T16:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126761.42" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846181" />
        <del:Value position="18" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T17:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T17:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126762.2" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846182" />
        <del:Value position="19" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T18:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T18:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126762.98" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846183" />
        <del:Value position="20" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T19:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T19:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126763.76" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846184" />
        <del:Value position="21" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T20:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T20:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126764.54" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846185" />
        <del:Value position="22" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T21:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T21:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126765.32" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846186" />
        <del:Value position="23" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T22:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T22:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126766.1" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846187" />
        <del:Value position="24" registrationDate="2021-10-27T22:01:51.000+00:00" readingDate="2021-08-28T23:00:00.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="2021-08-28T23:00:00.000+00:00" reading="126766.88" status="50" meterReadingId="1459846188" />
      </del:Values>
    </del:Data>
  </del:DataRows>
</del:DeliverMeterReading>
```

The code I have tried to access values is:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(N'http://schemas.fortum.com/amm/delivermeterreading' AS del)
SELECT
    t.file_name, t.file_created_time received_timestamp,
    h.value(N'(/del:MessageId)[1]','varchar(40)')
FROM
    load.t t
OUTER APPLY
    t.xml_data.nodes('/del:DeliverMeterReading/del:Header') AS m(h)
```

As t = table with xml_data column. I have tried some variation of select but can't figure out why it is showing null. I am including namespace in both the outer apply path and the value extraction select.

Running SQL Server 2019.

There is similar question [XML node values where xml data has colon syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635539/xml-node-values-where-xml-data-has-colon-syntax) which was answered by marc_s and I used that but just adjusted to try and get value between tag brackets vs inside tag (@ used for values inside tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal typo - in the `.value()`, do **not** include the leading '/':

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(N'http://schemas.fortum.com/amm/delivermeterreading' AS del)
SELECT
    t.file_name, t.file_created_time received_timestamp,
    h.value(N'(del:MessageId)[1]', 'varchar(40)')
FROM
    load.t t
OUTER APPLY
    t.xml_data.nodes('/del:DeliverMeterReading/del:Header') AS m(h)
```

Comment: i am getting duplicate rows if i have outer apply for "Data" level. It is 2nd level in 3 level hierachy. The issue seem to be when i have outer apply for both Data and for Values and i reference items in both Data and in Values in the select. If i just retreive Data section items or if i just get Values section item there is no issue but when i try and get from both it it creating duplicates in output.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `/` as mentioned.

Might be easier to use a `DEFAULT` namespace

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://schemas.fortum.com/amm/delivermeterreading')
SELECT
    t.file_name, t.file_created_time received_timestamp,
    h.value(N'(MessageId/text())[1]', 'varchar(40)')
FROM
    load.t t
OUTER APPLY
    t.xml_data.nodes('/DeliverMeterReading/Header') AS m(h)
```

Comment: I am getting duplicates when i try and get values from both Data section and Values section. I have updated the question with full XML example object. Tried following but only retreives 1st element.

Comment: To clarify, i have roughly the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25740689/how-to-query-another-attribute-from-next-level-of-xml-hierarchy-in-sql-server-20 (you answered correct answer) but i don't have values in tagg in higher hierarchy. I am trying to figure out how query would be adapted.

Comment: Most likely, you would `OUTER APPLY m.h.nodes('Values')`, but I suggest you open a new question for that, showing the code you are using now, and the full XML, and the expected result